# Problems while inserting element to last position of a list/index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, list-comprehension

I have a list like this:

```
[[['apple', 'bannana', 'lemon', 'watermelon'], ['apple', 'orange', 'peach', 'bannana']],
[['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'peach'], ['apple', 'grapes', 'peach', 'bannana']],
[['apple', 'orange', 'lemon', 'grapes'], ['apple', 'bannana', 'lemon', 'watermelon']]]
```

How can I add a new element, for example, 'hi' string to the last position of the first subsub list?

For example:

```
[[['apple', 'bannana', 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'hi'], ['apple', 'orange', 'peach', 'bannana']],
[['apple', 'orange', 'watermelon', 'peach', 'hi'], ['apple', 'grapes', 'peach', 'bannana']],
[['apple', 'orange', 'lemon', 'grapes', 'hi'], ['apple', 'bannana', 'lemon', 'watermelon']]]
```

I tried to, iterate and reconstruct the list. However, for some reason is adding more than one time the new string:

```
 for i in l:
     i[0].insert(len(i[0]), 'hi')
 print(i[0])
```

Is there any other pythonic way of doing this? What I dont want is to end up reconstructing with more lists the original list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.insert` is a generalization of `list.append` that can insert the element anywhere (and does so relatively inefficiently, where `append` has amortized `O(1)` complexity). If you just want to "insert" at the end of the `list`, use `append` instead:

```
for i in l:
    i[0].append('hi')
```

If your `l` `list`s are always composed of two items, you can use iterable unpacking to avoid indexing (and ideally, give each part a useful name, instead of just `i`), e.g.:

```
for part1, part2 in l:  # Or since you never use part2, just for part1, _ in l:
    part1.append('hi')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I got repetead `hi` at the end of `part1`

Comment: @J.Doe: Sounds like either 1) You ran both code examples, not just one (or ran one of them twice) or 2) Some or all of your `part1`s are aliases of one another (they're actually the *same* `list`), so each `append` is modifying the same `list`, and therefore `append`ing twice. It [works as written](https://tio.run/##lY/RasMwDEXf/RWX9sHpMIVub4V@Qz8gM0PN1CTFlY3tdPTr0zQZJYVBmV50Je65SOGaGy8ffe@wQ1mWmkJwrA30gURI6C4dn73cxQ9ljmd2w2QNZmYfSepRBaaqmfPWGlX@aZ2lPcDn2DpS4PTP2Me1v/Rz5Ku3rFXq6CMCxbwxY3tHK3BbYIl9RGqlYlx9B@ELR3SJJ5fBqUsZM/hrAhWGGlfr4QyW70I3rV4pFWIruXhzBonDbvEpi1Xf3wA).

Comment: Oh, or option #3 (which I hit while making that link in my last comment): You accidentally initialized `l` by pasting from your desired end result (so `'hi'` already existed on all the `part1`s before you started, and you added a second one with the `append`). Option 4 would be "You've got code you haven't shown us that is running the `append` loop twice".

Comment: Is there any other alternative option? for some reason I am still getting repeated `hi` elements at the end of the nested list

Comment: @J.Doe: Option #4 covers a lot of stuff. You can update your question to add a [MCVE], but make sure that the code really does reproduce your problem run in isolation.